# JQuery wildcard for class in "on" commend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).on('focus', '.mask-date, .mask-phone', function () {
 ...    
}):
```

For the above statement is there a way to use wildcard, like below. except that one does not work.

```
$(document).on('focus', '[class^=mask-]', function () {
 ...
});
```

Comment: Your wildcard should work, though you may need to put quotes around the value.  Also show us the html that it will match on.  `^=` requires the class to be at the very start of the attribute.

Comment: That is an attribute equals selector. If the class you are targeting isn't the first class in the attribute, that selector won't function the way you expect.

Comment: Use `[class^="mask-"]` instead. I assume the `-` at the end requires quoting.

Comment: Add a `mask` class to elements with either class on them. Then you can just use `'.mask'` instead of all of this other craziness :).

Comment: ^ That's a valid solution, though it doesn't help the OP learn why their current approach is not working

Comment: Related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615334/jquery-finding-partial-class-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your selector is that it's matching against the `class` attribute literally. If one of the inputs has

```
class="foo mask-date"
```

it won't match, because `mask-` is not at the beginning of the attribute as required by the `^=` modifier. You can do better with:

```
[class*=mask-]
```

which will match anywhere in the attribute. This could get a false match if you also had something like `class="bitmask-blah"`, but that's probably unlikely.