# jQuery/JS ES5 - find partial name of data attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, ecmascript-5

I have wrapper with two randomly injected kinds of banners on site - one at time - only difference is that one kind uses `data-abcde-zoneid="10"` and second is not.
I have to select those that doesn't contain `data-abcde-zoneid="10"` where `abcde` is random string and do some things with it.

Searching only by value or adding class to that element isn't possible.
The only solution is to find element which contains `-zoneid="10"` or opposite to it.
I can't change injected html for banners.

I'm aware of finding class name or attribute value like in [jQuery: Finding partial class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615334/jquery-finding-partial-class-name/33615377) and I've tried use those to find solution but with no result.

Comment: You can loop through each `element`s `Object.values(element.attributes)` for a match.

Comment: @mplungjan I am blind or what? :) I've tried this and everywhere they are talking about  [attribute$="value"] but I need something like  [sth$='attribute="value" ']...

Comment: @JamesCoyle - that's more helpful :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/p2hkyuwj/

Comment: ES6: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/b36hdq18/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are duplicates out there, they were very verbose so I decided to post some shorter versions:

You can filter -  if you need, change the zoneid and value to vars and wrap in a function:

jQuery with ES6 [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/b36hdq18/)

```js
$("div").filter(
    (_, div) => (
      Array.from(div.attributes).filter( // Array from NamedNodeMap
        (item) => item.name.indexOf("zoneid") !== -1 && item.value !== "10")
    ).length > 0
  )
  .addClass("red")
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-xxxxx-zoneid="10">
  XXXXXX 10
</div>
<div data-xxxx-something-else="z" data-xxxxx-zoneid="20">
  XXXXXX 20
</div>
<div data-yyy-zoneid="10">
  yyy 10
</div>
<div data-yyy-zoneid="30">
  yyy 30
</div>
```

jQuery for older browsers [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/p2hkyuwj/)

```js
$("div").filter(function() {
    var namedNodeMap = this.attributes;
    for (var i = 0; i < namedNodeMap.length; i++) {
      var item = namedNodeMap.item(i);
      if (item.name.indexOf("zoneid") !== -1 && item.value !== "10") {
        return true
      }
    }
  })
  .addClass("red")
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-xxxxx-zoneid="10">
  XXXXXX 10
</div>
<div data-xxxx-something-else="z" data-xxxxx-zoneid="20">
  XXXXXX 20
</div>
<div data-yyy-zoneid="10">
  yyy 10
</div>
<div data-yyy-zoneid="30">
  yyy 30
</div>
```