# Jquery : How to get all value of inputs element with array names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html code which looks like below :

```
<input type="text" name="fruits[apple]" value="true">
<input type="text" name="fruits[orange]" value="false">
<input type="text" name="fruits[mango]" value="true">
```

How do I select all the fruits and get their respective values? I'm looking for an object like

```
{
  "apple": true,
  "orange": false,
  "mango": true
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615334/jquery-finding-partial-class-name/33615377#33615377

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select elements which start with `fruits[`, and map to their values:

```js
const vals = $('[name^="fruits["]')
  .map((_, input) => input.value)
  .get();
console.log(vals);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="fruits[apple]" value="true">
<input type="text" name="fruits[orange]" value="false">
<input type="text" name="fruits[mango]" value="true">
```

Keep in mind that the `.value` of inputs are *strings* - if you need booleans instead, you'll have to do so more explicitly:

```js
const vals = $('[name^="fruits["]')
  .map((_, input) => input.value === 'true')
  .get();
console.log(vals);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="fruits[apple]" value="true">
<input type="text" name="fruits[orange]" value="false">
<input type="text" name="fruits[mango]" value="true">
```

If you need the unique part of the `name` as well, then `reduce` into an object of key-value pairs (and may as well drop the jQuery if using `reduce`):

```js
const vals = [...document.querySelectorAll('[name^="fruits["]')]
  .reduce((a, { name, value }) => {
    const key = name.match(/[^[]+(?=\])/)[0];
    a[key] = value === 'true';
    return a;
  }, {});
console.log(vals);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fruits[apple]" value="true">
<input type="text" name="fruits[orange]" value="false">
<input type="text" name="fruits[mango]" value="true">
```

Comment: wow! Can't believe It, you are really fast. I will have to wait 12 minutes to accept this answer. lol

Comment: I want to get them as key value pair format. fruits['apple' => true, 'mango' => false]

Comment: Use `reduce` instead, and may as well remove the jQuery at this point

Comment: @Tintin I would question, if you want to format them with the object keys like that, why build the html with the names not like that?