# Event of selector of 2 dimensional array name won't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This won't work:

```
    <input type="text" name="start_time[0][0]" value="00">
    <input type="text" name="start_time[0][1]" value="01">
    <input type="text" name="start_time[1][0]" value="10">
    <input type="text" name="start_time[1][1]" value="11">

    $("form[name='fare-form'] input[name='start_time[][]'").click(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

If I specify array indices, it'll work. And I'm presuming using 1-dimensional array works which I've used elsewhere.

Why won't it work?

I learnt it has to match exactly. So in the case where I do 1-dimensional array such as:

```
<input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="2">

$("form[name='fare-form'] input[name='start_time[]'").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

This works because Javascript or whatever will automatically create array of two indices but the reference of start_time[] in event will point to both elements of array?

Comment: None of those names have `[][]` in them.  All the `[]` have numbers in them

Comment: Give all of them a class of `start_time` and select by the class.  done.

Comment: I used class. But out of curiousity, why doesn't it work? Care to explain?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615334/jquery-finding-partial-class-name/33615377#33615377

Comment: It doesn't work because the value you place in the selector, ie. `input[name='start_time[]']` need to *exactly* match the attribute on the element. In your case, the first `input` would be `input[name='start_time[0][0]']`. Also note that your attribute selector in both examples is missing a closing `]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `[name=...]`, the name has to match exactly, it doesn't do any kind of pattern matching. `start_time[][]` is not an exact match for `start_time[0][0]` or any of the other names in the form.

You can use `input[name^=start_time]` to match any name that begins with `start_time`.

See [jQuery Attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) for all the different ways you can match attributes in jQuery selectors. There's no form that will do the kind of pattern matching you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! Spot on with explanation.