# jQuery selector multiple select menus / regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to select multiple select menus via jquery selector + regex, however, I keep getting `unrecognized expression`

Here is what I have tried

```js
$(':regex(class,kt-trxselect-[0-9])');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control kt-trxselect-0">
    <option></option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
</select>


<select class="form-control kt-trxselect-1">
    <option></option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does it exist? I find no mention of it in the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615334/jquery-finding-partial-class-name/33615377#33615377

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe regex support you talk of was only available via a [custom jQuery Selector](https://j11y.io/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) written in 2009.

I would recommend going with standard [CSS "begins with" style selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2178504/406712) if you can.

Or perhaps adding an additional class `kt-trxselect` which would be easy to match on.