# Get all classes with the string partial name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have randomly generated classes in my HTML file.
`class="page-index-1`, `class="page-index-2`, `class="page-index-3`, etc.
I need get these classes using only the prefix `page-index-`and with this get all the classes.
I tried to use JQuery `$('div[class*=page-index-]').find();` this gives me a huge object but I can't find the classes inside of this.

Does someone have any idea about how can I get these classes?
I need to get to reorder as I need it.

Comment: Incremental class/id attributes are generally a bad idea for the exact reason you're describing. Give all the elements the same class and the problem goes away and your code quality improves.

Comment: As above with the added info to add the `-1` `-2` etc parts as `data-` attributes, eg `<div class='page-index' data-page='2'>2</div>`

Comment: Please include the code you've used.  `$(selector).find()` will return 0 elements - so if it's a "huge object" you're probably looking at the empty jquery collection.  Check with `.length`, eg `$('div[class*=page-index-]').find().length === 0)`  - in your case you want just `$('div[class*=page-index-]')` - without the `.find()` as `.find()` says "get child items that match null" (which is nothing)

Comment: You can use the CSS starts with selector:
JQuery: `$('[class^="page-index-"]')`
Vanilla: `document.querySelectorAll('[class^="page-index-"]')`. As freedomn said, using .find() will get you all child elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: Finding partial class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615334/jquery-finding-partial-class-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this:

```js
const list = []
$('[class]').each(function() {
  this.classList.forEach(function(className) {
    if (!className.indexOf('page-index-')) {
      list.push(className)
    }
  })
})
console.log(list) //list contains generated class
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-index-1"></div>
<div class="page-in"></div>
<div class="page-index-2"></div>
<div class="page-index-3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this worlked